# How can I script the importation of project in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I work in a place where configuration management is a bit peculiar, we can have different versions of the software on our hard drives.

As a result, I often have to import my projects back into IntelliJ. I wonder if the "Project from Existing Sources..." project import can be scripted? A bit like a Shell script, where all I'd have to do is give the script my project trees. Load the script and run it in IntelliJ, so that it shows me all my projects.

I sometimes have a dozen projects, so I have to do File => New => Project from Existing Sources 10 times...

So I'm looking to automate this process, even if it means modifying the tree structures by hand, but is it possible to bring up my working environments automatically with IntelliJ? Do I need a plugin for this ?